# Second product image on category page

Tags: magento2, product, category, image, listing

I'm trying to display second image of a product in a category page on hover. I managed to get images by `$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()` but I have problems with resizing them to `category_page_grid` or `category_page_list` size. My question is: how can I resize those images to default category page image size or maybe is there a way to get second image with the same method as default image by `$productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $imageDisplayArea)`?